# unable to cast object of type 'rncamera.rctcamera viewmanager'

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-native, surface

I am doing a little project example and I'm facing a problem with the camera on Surface 2 with windows 10 pro 64bit (The camera is working on Android devices)

**This is the problem:**

`unable to cast object of type 'rncamera.rctcamera viewmanager' to type 'reactnative.uimanager.iviewparentmanager'`

I want to know if some here can give a hint what is going on there.